# Theory for describing how mathematical entities will behave

Tags: calculus, group-theory

I've realized that operations like adding and multiplication can mean different things under different situations. For example, the multiplication of real numbers is the same as scaling while imaginary numbers is rotating. I was wondering if calculus or group theory or if there is a mathematical theory to shows how mathematical entities will behave under an operation and space (cartesian, Hilbert space, etc.) and why.

Thanks for your time,
Jackson

Answer (score 2):

Well, your question should be formalized a little better, but you should be happy to know that to almost every algebraic object (groups, rings, associative algebras, Lie algebras) corresponds a [representation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory). The details of this depend *heavily* on the class of objects studied, but the idea is substantially studying the morphisms associating a matrix to every element of your algebraic object.

Perhaps, the simplest case would be the representations of a group $G$ as a subset of bijective linear maps $\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^n$.

A representation, in this case, would be a group homomorphism $\phi: G\to \text{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$. The knowledge of these maps provides a useful tool to the study of groups, for instance because it provides a most natural way to run calculations (and many, much deeper results).

In your example, you were intuitively describing the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}^*:=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ through an injective map $\psi:\mathbb{C}^*\hookrightarrow \text{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$.

(Actually, yours was an *attempt*, because your description has a couple of major flaws)

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on how you mean, if you mean in a specific manner then the answer is a no because it all depends on the definition of the operation in question. If you on the other hand put certain restrictions on your freedom, by limiting it to that it MUST have certain properties, we can start predicting it with for example group theory, abstract algebra, topology and many other fields of mathematics.